# gs:0x10 Segmentation Fault

Tags: linux, x86, segmentation-fault

For some reason my program receives a SIGSEV error at this line:

```
    mov edi, DWORD PTR gs:[eax-0x71]
```

where:

```
    eax - 0x71 = 0x9881668
    [0x9881668] = 0x00000010
    gs = 0x33
```

edi should contain the address of __kernel_vsyscall but...something goes wrong. What is happening? This is on Ubuntu 11.10 BTW.

Comment: Is the presented code part of a C or C++ (or some other language) source file, or are you programming directly in assembler? No matter what language it is, you could show some more surrounding code to help us get a better context about what you are trying to do.

Comment: This is directly in assembly. I am trying to do an set up an indirect call to __kernel_syscall for learning purposes and the segmentation fault occurs only within the context of this line. I don't know if I can't move gs:0x10 into edi fo some weird reason, but the reason for the sigsev is either extremely obvious or incredibly arcane. Not sure which one though.